# Is there a method to smoothly breaking up a linear transformation into several steps?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a real square matrix. I want to smoothly apply $M$ over $K$ steps rather than just $1$ step. I came up with some conditions for this to be true. Define a function that takes in the $M$ and the current step $k$. Then
$$\Pi_{k=1}^{K} f(M,k) = M$$
$$f(M,1) \approx 1 $$
$$f(M,K) = 1 $$

What I wanted to know is if this problem is already solved or if there is already a good candidate function $f(M,K)$ that is easily computable. Also, I need $f(M,k)$ to map to the space of real square matrices.

Comment: You are asking to take the k-th root of a matrix? If the n x n matrix has n eigenvectors then you can transform it to into its Jordan form, which in this case will be a diagonal matrix,  and simply apply n-th root to the diagonal entries.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about this, but if $M$ is not symmetric positive-semidefinite then the resulting in between matrices are not guaranteed to be real.

Comment: Then lat them be complex, what harm done? Only if the Jordan form is not a diagonal matrix things get nasty.

Comment: As far as I remember (but this is long ago and I'm missing details) you can mimic that by using $2\times 2$ diagonal block matrices.

Comment: Without more conditions on how you want the intermediate steps to behave this is very underdetermined. For example, you could compute the QR decomposition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) and then separately break up the orthogonal bit into a sequence of rotations and the upper triangular bit into a sequence of shears. Does that make sense for your application? Who knows!

Comment: What @QiaochuYuan is pointing out is that there is more than one way to get from $A$ to $B$, and that there might not even be one single "straight and narrow" path. But I think, as for now, this is beyond your question.